# Continue loop(for) at position break(Vector C++)

Tags: c++

I have a code:

```
uint8_t x = 0;
typedef std::vector<Data> Data_Record;
const Data_Record& getData() const;
main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        get1();
        get2();
    }
}
void get1()
{
    for (const auto& dataRecord : file.getData())
    {
        if( x==10)
        {
           break;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

You see dataRecord read at `position 10`. How to continue `get1()` with next dataRecord (`postion 11`). Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You have to rewrite your code, [coroutine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) or handle that yourself (with a class?).

Comment: Use and old-style `for` loop with an iterator. Remember the iterator when breaking, and then use it as a starting point of the next loop.

Comment: What should happens when all elements have been processed? restart, end the main loop?

Comment: @Jarod42 it is only send data and continue to read data

Comment: You cannot do it in the `get1()`. You have to make changes in `getData()` or better to write an overload of `getData()` which returns from where it left last.

Comment: @hungcuiga1 What do want to achieve? What is your question? Do you want to get the values at the 11th position? Why is the function 'get1' called in an endless loop? Please, clarify, edit your question to make it reasonable to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `while` loop, you can try using a for loop.

```cpp
uint8_t x = 0;
size_t currentPosition = 0;

void get1()
{
    const auto& data = file.getData();
    
    for (size_t i = currentPosition; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        const auto& dataRecord = data[i];
        
        if (x == 10)
        {
            x = 0;
            currentPosition = i + 1;
            return;
        }
        
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not a question. The code in the question is unclear - and seem to have some misconception or at least strange concepts. I my opinion it is unreasonable to answer, don't you agree?

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann kind of?

Comment: I asked hungcuiga1 to clarity. Let's see the outcome.

Comment: Dear @ALL, sorry for late, this issue bucause I bad in c++, just use vector[i] is solove